# Nodejs http.request strange delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have found strange delay of http.request function. Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var app = express();
app.get('/aaa',function(req,res) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.json({"a":1});
    },500);
});
app.get('/bbb',function(req,res){
    var options = {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/aaa',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var request = http.request(options, function(result) {
        result.on("data",function(){

        });
        res.json({"b":2});
    });

    request.on('error', function() {
        res.json({"b":2});
    });

    request.end();
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
});
```

Client call /bbb, then it's handler call /aaa and within 500ms result returns back to client.
I tried to measure response time in different situations using Apache Bench:

1) 1000 requests with 1 concurrent requests.
Average response time: 500ms
2) 1000 requests with 50 concurrent requests.
Average response time: 5000ms
3) 1000 requests with 100 concurrent requests.
Average response time: 10000ms

Why response time is growing?

It's okay when I call /aaa directly

Comment: Problably because you are making more requests and the server cant respond then all at once.

Comment: what is app.get? it's not part of node.js and it could be slowing you down...

Comment: app.get is Express framework

Comment: It's not the server/express which is being overwhelmed, I believe it's the internal HTTP client used to make GET requests to /aaa... I wrote an answer below to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not unusual behaviour. The HTTP Client used in the callback to /bbb (`http.request`) is limited to 5 concurrent sockets per host. In other words, it can only make 5 HTTP requests in parallel. You can find reference to this [here in the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets)

Just to confirm you're hitting the limit, you should run your tests using 5 and 6 concurrent requests. You'll see (as I did) average response time drops significantly at 6 concurrent requests. This is because the 6th concurrent request will be queued until one of the 5 preceeding requests to `/aaa` is completed.

To answer your question about why response time grows: The more concurrency you add in your benchmark, the more average response time will go up because each request has to wait for more requests in the queue to finish before it can get a socket.

You can increase the number of concurrent sockets your HTTP client can handle by modifying the [default agent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent) like this:

```
var http = require("http");
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 10;
```

You can also circumvent pooling altogether by passing `agent:false` to  `http.get` like so:

```
http.get({hostname:'localhost', port:80, path:'/', agent:false}, function (res) {
  // Do stuff
})
```

**Update (8th Feb 2015)**

An important change regarding this answer has come up in [Node v 0.12.0](http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/02/06/node-v0-12-0-stable/).

> maxSockets are no longer limited to 5. The default is now set to
>   Infinity with the developer and the operating system given control
>   over how many simultaneous connections an application can keep open to
>   a given host.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and it is resolved by keeping it very simple get request as below

```
var req = http.get(requestUrl)
req.end();
```